# How to use "$dateToString" in Mongo criteriaQuery (Spring Boot)

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework, criteria

i use SpringBoot(v1.5.10),SpringData and MongoDb;

```
db.login.aggregate(
[
    { 
        "$match" : {
            "user._id" : NumberLong(204)
        }
    }, 
    { 
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : {
               "datetime" : { $dateToString: { format: "%d-%m-%Y", date: "$datetime"}}, 
                "ip" : "$ip",


            },
             count: { $sum: 1 }   
        }
    }

]);
```

- 2011-01-10 count 5
- 2011-01-16 count 16

  ```
      Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("user._id").is(paramuserid).andOperator(
          Criteria.where("datetime").gte(paramfirstdate),
          Criteria.where("datetime").lt(paramseconddate)
                  );
  AggregationOperation match = Aggregation.match(criteria);   

  List<AggregationOperation> aggregationoperations = new ArrayList <AggregationOperation>();  
  aggregationoperations.add(match);
  aggregationoperations.add(Aggregation.group("datetime"));  
  AggregationResults<?> aggregationresults = this.mngT.aggregate(Aggregation.newAggregation(aggregationoperations), Login.class, Object.class);
  ```
- 2011-01-10 09:00:01 count 1
- 2011-01-10 09:15:00 count 1

Mongo aggregate group datetime without "time" , I try  similar criteriaquery not working because  group with time part. How to use "$dateToString" in criteriaquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved.

```
Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("user._id").is(paramuserid).andOperator(
            Criteria.where("datetime").gte(paramfirstdate),
            Criteria.where("datetime").lt(paramseconddate)
                    );
    AggregationOperation match = Aggregation.match(criteria);   

    List<AggregationOperation> aggregationoperations = new ArrayList <AggregationOperation>();  
    aggregationoperations.add(match);
    aggregationoperations.add(Aggregation.project("ip","datetime").andExpression("datetime").dateAsFormattedString("%d-%m-%Y").as("formateddate"));
    aggregationoperations.add(Aggregation.group("ip","formateddate").count().as("TOT"));
    AggregationResults<?> aggregationresults = this.mngT.aggregate(Aggregation.newAggregation(aggregationoperations), Login.class, Object.class);
```